# Забрать значение из spinner в переменную. Android

Tags: android

Не получается присвоить значение переменной mark_id вне метода spinner_mark.setOnItemSelectedListener(). Внутри все работает, снаружи null.

```
public class BuyCarPolisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
public String  mark_name;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_car_polis);

    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
    }

    try {
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }

    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM casco_marka WHERE pop = ?", new String[]{"1"});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    final List<String> mark = new ArrayList<String>();
    mark.add(cursor.getString(1));
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        mark.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();

    // адаптер
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_mark = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mark);
    adapter_mark.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner spinner_mark = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_mark);
    spinner_mark.setAdapter(adapter_mark);

    spinner_mark.setPrompt("Title");

    spinner_mark.setSelection(2);


    spinner_mark.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            mark_name = mark.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + mark_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Тут показывает значение.
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + mark_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Тут показывает null
```

Comment: Так происходит потому, что поле класса `mark_name` не имеет начальной инициализации, какое то значение оно получает только после того, как колбэк `onItemSelected()` сработает (то есть когда в спиннере выберут какое -то значение). Вам нужно установить полю какое то значение по умолчанию при его объявлении, например `public String  mark_name =" ";`

Comment: Спасибо, пробему для себя уже решил.

Answer (score 0):

Мне необходим был вложенный взаимосвязанный спиннер с запонением из базы. Может кому пригодится. Проблему для себя решил вот так:

```
public class BuyCarPolisActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
public String  mark_name, model_name;
TextView result;
Button button;
Spinner spinner_year, spinner_mark, spinner_model;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_car_polis);
    result = findViewById(R.id.text_result);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
    }

    try {
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }



    Cursor cursor_year = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM year", null);
    cursor_year.moveToFirst();
    final List<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
    years.add(cursor_year.getString(0));
    while (cursor_year.moveToNext()) {
        years.add(cursor_year.getString(0));
    }
    cursor_year.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_year = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);
    adapter_year.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_year= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
    spinner_year.setAdapter(adapter_year);
    spinner_year.setPrompt("Title");
    spinner_year.setSelection(0);

    spinner_year.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Тут показывает значение.
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });


    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM casco_marka WHERE pop = ?", new String[]{"1"});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    final List<String> mark = new ArrayList<String>();
    mark.add(cursor.getString(1));
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        mark.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();

    // адаптер
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_mark = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mark);
    adapter_mark.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_mark = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_mark);
    spinner_model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_model);
    spinner_mark.setAdapter(adapter_mark);

    spinner_mark.setPrompt("Title");

    spinner_mark.setSelection(0);


    spinner_mark.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            mark_name = mark.get(position);
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM casco_marka WHERE marka = ?", new String[]{mark_name});
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String mark_id = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            load_spinner_model(mark_id, spinner_model);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

}

    private void load_spinner_model(String mark_id, Spinner spinner_model){
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM casco_mdl WHERE marka_id = ? AND pop = ?", new String[]{mark_id,"1"});

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        final List<String> model = new ArrayList<String>();
        model.add(cursor.getString(1));
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            model.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }
        cursor.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_model = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, model);
        adapter_model.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_model.setAdapter(adapter_model);
        spinner_model.setSelection(0);
        spinner_model.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                model_name = model.get(position);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    result.setText(spinner_year.getSelectedItem().toString() + " " + spinner_mark.getSelectedItem().toString()+ " " +spinner_model.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

}